# Citation undefined

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question mark instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-instead-of-citation-number)

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Plantilla de un artículo para publicar en la Revista Colombiana de Estadística
% *************************************************************************************
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Establecer primero el idioma principal del artículo, por defecto es español; para
% utilizar otro idioma, cambiar el comando "\documentclass{revcoles}" por el comando
% "\documentclass[english]{revcoles}" o por "\documentclass[portuguese]{revcoles}"
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{revcoles}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para la carga de los paquetes por parte del autor
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para colocar las definiciones especiales por parte del autor
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------




% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio utilizado para colocar las palabras que necesitan partición silábica
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\hyphenation{Colombia  mul-ti-va-ria-do pro-ba-bi-li-dad es-ta-dís-ti-ca}
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para ingresar el título del artículo
% "maintitle = " título original del artículo
% "secondtitle = " título del artículo traducido al idioma alterno
% "shorttitle = " título corto (opcional) para el encabezado
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title[maintitle = Revista  Colombiana de Estadística. Guía para autores,
       secondtitle = Revista Colombiana de Estadística. Guidelines for Authors,
       shorttitle = Guía para autores
]
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para ingresar el(los) autor(es) del artículo de forma individual.
% opción "firstname = " nombres completos de cada autor
% opción "surname = " primer apellido de cada autor
% opción "numberinstitution = " número que identifica la institución a la que pertenece
%         el autor, en caso de haber solo una institución el campo puede ser eliminado
% opción "affiliation = " afiliación o cargo que desempeña el autor en la institución
% opción "email = " dirección electrónica del autor (preferiblemente institucional)
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{authors}
\author[firstname = Piedad,
        surname = Urdinola Contreras,
        numberinstitution = 1,
        affiliation = Editora Revista Colombiana de Estadística,
        email = bpurdinolac@bt.unal.edu.co]
\author[firstname = Campo Elías,
        surname = Pardo,
        numberinstitution = 1,
        affiliation = Profesor asociado,
        email = cepardot@unal.edu.co]
\author[firstname = Edwin Camilo,
        surname = Cubides,
        numberinstitution = 2,
        affiliation = Profesor ocasional,
        email = eccubidesg@unal.edu.co]
\end{authors}
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para ingresar la información de la(s) institución(es) a la(s)
% cual(es) pertenece(n) el(los) autor(es)
% Usar un comando "\institute"  por cada una de las diferentes instituciones.
% Los campos "subdivision" y "division" son opcionales
% Los campos "institution", "city" y "country" son obligatorios
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{institutions}
     \institute[subdivision = Departamento de Estadística,
                division = Facultad de Ciencias,
                institution = Universidad Nacional de Colombia,
                city = Bogotá,
                country = Colombia]
     \institute[subdivision = Departamento de Matemáticas,
                division = Facultad de Ciencias,
                institution = Universidad Nacional de Colombia,
                city = Bogotá,
                country = Colombia]
\end{institutions}
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CUERPO DEL DOCUMENTO
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para colocar el resumen en el idioma principal y las palabras clave
% !!No dejar salto de línea entre el resumen y el comando \keywords{.}¡¡
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{mainabstract}
Se dan las instrucciones de presentación de los artículos para la Revista Colombiana de Estadística, utilizando \LaTeX.
Este texto está escrito en el formato de un artículo (\emph{Guidelines for authors RevColEs.tex}) y puede utilizarse
como plantilla, reemplazando este contenido por el del artículo. Se requieren los archivos \emph{revcoles.cls},
\emph{references.bib} y \emph{graph\_example.eps}.%
%
\keywords{Formato en \LaTeX\ para documentos, Revista Colombiana de Estadística}
\end{mainabstract}
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio reservado para colocar el resumen en el idioma secundario y las palabras clave
% !!No dejar salto de línea entre el resumen y el comando \keywords{.}¡¡
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{secondaryabstract}
This document gives the instructions to prepare a \LaTeX\ version of the papers to be presented in the Revista
Colombiana de Estadística. The document is written using a \LaTeX\ format (file \emph{Guidelines for authors
RevColEs.tex}) and can be used as a template just replacing its contents by the terms of the paper to be presented. It
is necessary to use also the files \emph{revcoles.cls}, \emph{references.bib} and \emph{graph\_example.eps}.%
%
\keywords{\LaTeX\ format for documents, Revista Colombiana de Estadística}
\end{secondaryabstract}
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Título de la primera sección
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introducción}
Este documento es una guía para escribir los artículos que van a ser sometidos a la Revista Colombiana de Estadística.
El autor puede renombrar este archivo (\emph{Guidelines for authors RevColEs.tex}) y reemplazar su contenido por el del artículo.

\section{Formato del texto}\label{ejem}
El formato del texto queda determinado al utilizar \emph{revcoles} como clase de documento
(\verb"\documentclass{revcoles}"). En el directorio de trabajo deben estar los archivos: \emph{revcoles.cls}, el cual
no se debe modificar; y \emph{references.bib}, en el cual el autor debe introducir los datos de las referencias en
formato \BibTeX.

\subsection{Artículos en inglés o portugués}
Para artículos en inglés (portugués) basta incluir la opción
\emph{english} (\emph{portuguese}) en \verb"\documentclass":

\verb"\documentclass[english]{revcoles}" o

\verb"\documentclass[portuguese]{revcoles}".

Se debe tener en cuenta que el título es el del idioma del artículo
(inglés o portugués) y el título traducido es en español.

El \verb"\mainabstract" es en inglés (portugués) y el
\verb"\secondaryabstract" es en español.

\subsection{Autores}

Los nombres de los autores deben ir completos y acompañados del primer apellido solamente. Los comentarios en el fuente
de esta plantilla (\emph{Guidelines for authors RevColEs.tex}) ayudan escribir correctamente los datos de los autores.

\subsection{Pertenencia institucional}
Cuando los autores pertenecen a la misma institución y dependencia,
el nombre de esta se coloca una sola vez.

Si los autores pertenecen a instituciones diferentes o a la misma institución pero a dependencias
diferentes, cada una de estas se debe especificar individualmente.

El comando \verb"\institute" permite especificar cada institución y debe estar anidada dentro del entorno
\verb"institutions".

Los comentarios en el fuente de esta plantilla (\emph{Guidelines for authors\linebreak RevColEs.tex}) ayudan a entender
estos aspectos.

\subsection{Resumen y Abstract}

El resumen debe incluir, de manera sintetizada, los objetivos, la
metodología y las conclusiones, no incluir figuras o tablas y no
debe exceder los $1500$ caracteres.

\section{Secciones}
La numeración de las secciones debe hacerse con números arábigos, el
título \textbf{Referencias} debe ir alineado a la izquierda, en
negrilla y sin numeración (\emph{estilo predeterminado de esta
plantilla}).


\section{Tablas, gráficas y ecuaciones}

\subsection{Tablas} Si la tabla contiene datos numéricos debe
tenerse en cuenta (ver tabla \ref{tabla1}):
\begin{itemize}
\item Los números van centrados siempre y cuando tengan la misma
cantidad de dígitos, de lo contrario deben ir alineados con el
margen derecho del título. \item Cuando las tablas tienen datos
con cifras decimales, el número de éstas debe ser igual dentro de
la misma columna, pudiendo variar de columna a columna.
\end{itemize}
%
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{\small{Valores estimados para la estructura factorial
$2\times 6$, con $m=10$ datos faltantes.}}\label{tabla1}
\centering {\small
\begin{tabular}{ccrc}\hline
$y_2$   &
$\hat{y}_2$ &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$e_2$}   &
$\hat{y}_2^*$\\ \hline
52.1    & 54.2  &  $-2.76$      & 51.4  \\
52.1    & 54.2  &  $ 1.10$      & 53.1  \\
52.3    & 52.4  &  $-0.71$      & 51.7  \\
59.9    & 59.3  &  $ 0.44$      & 59.7  \\
59.9    & 59.3  &  $ 0.80$      & 60.1  \\
51.7    & 54.0  &  $-1.33$      & 52.7  \\
63.9    & 61.3  &  $ 0.27$      & 61.6  \\
63.9    & 61.3  &  $ 1.31$      & 62.6  \\
67.2    & 66.4  &  $-0.44$      & 66.0  \\
64.8    & 61.0  &  $ 2.12$      & 63.1  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

Cuando es una tabla con datos alfanuméricos, estos deben ir
centrados (ver tabla \ref{tabla2}).

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering\small \caption{Análisis de varianza basado en las sumas
de cuadrados tipo III.}\label{tabla2}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}\hline
\parbox[c][0.9\height]{18mm}{\centering\smallskip Causa de\\Variación\smallskip} &%
\parbox[c][0.9\height]{25mm}{\centering\smallskip Grados de\\Libertad\smallskip} &%
\parbox[c][0.9\height]{16mm}{\centering\smallskip Suma de\\Cuadrados\smallskip} &%
\parbox[c][0.9\height]{15mm}{\centering\smallskip Cuadrado\\Medio\smallskip}& Estadístico F\\\hline
Modelo & $p+r-2$&$SCM^*$&$CMM^*$&$FG^*=\frac{CMM^*}{CME}$\\ %\hline
E. Fijos & $p-1$&$SCMF^*$&$CMMF^*$&$FF=\frac{CMMF^*}{CME}$\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\subsection{Gráficas} Deben estar en formato postscript encapsulado
(eps), a tinta negra y deben grabarse en el mismo directorio en el cual esté el
archivo \LaTeX. %

El título debe ir en la parte inferior y centrado, los dígitos de
la escala del eje vertical deben estar horizontales y el texto de
las etiquetas debe estar en el idioma del artículo, tal como se
indica en la figura \ref{figura1}, que presenta la serie de
inflación para el período comprendido entre enero de 1998 y
diciembre de 2005 \cite{Santana}.

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{graph_example.eps}
  \caption{Serie de inflación: enero/98-diciembre/05.}\label{figura1}
\end{figure}


\subsection{Ecuaciones} Van como se muestra en \eqref{equ1}, sin puntuación al final:

\begin{equation}\label{equ1}
    y=W\mu+Z\theta+e
\end{equation}

Las matrices deben ir entre corchetes cuadrados como se observa en
\eqref{equ2}:

\begin{equation}\label{equ2}
\begin{bmatrix}
W'R^{-1}W&W'R^{-1}Z\\
Z'R^{-1}W&Z'R^{-1}Z+D^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu \\ \theta
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
W'R^{-1}y\\
Z'R^{-1}y
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}


\section{Citas bibliográficas} Para las \textbf{Referencias} se
utiliza el paquete
Harvard\footnote{http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/harvard.ps},
formato autor-año. Estas deben realizarse con el programa \BibTeX    el cual requiere que las referencias sean grabadas en un archivo
de extensión \emph{.bib} \cite[pp. 205--215]{Castro-03}.

En la sección referencias solamente deben aparecer las citadas en el
texto. Las citas dentro del texto se introducen mediante el comando:
\verb"\cite{clave}".

Por ejemplo: \cite{Caballero-86}, \cite{Dodge-85},
\cite{Conover-81}, \cite{Searle-92}.

Para agregar algún texto que preceda la etiqueta dentro de la citación se debe
utilizar el comando: \verb"\citeaffixed{clave}{texto}".

Por ejemplo: para incluir ecuaciones numeradas en \LaTeX\ se utiliza el entorno
\verb"\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}" \citeaffixed[p. 86]{Castro-03}{\emph{véase}}\dots


Si el nombre del autor forma parte del texto, el comando que se debe utilizar
es: \verb"\citeasnoun{clave}". Por ejemplo:

\begin{itemize}

\item Según el trabajo de \citeasnoun{Borges-05}\dots

\item Los modelos propuestos por \citeasnoun{Dodge-85}\dots

\item Tal como lo indica \citeasnoun{Conover-81} en su trabajo de \dots

\item El algoritmo se programo utilizando \citeasnoun{R} \dots

\end{itemize}

\section{Conversión a PDF}
Para conservar el formato de la página, la conversión de \emph{dvi}
a \emph{pdf} se debe hacer de la siguiente manera:
\begin{itemize}
\item Convertir \emph{dvi} $\rightsquigarrow$ \emph{ps}.
\item Convertir \emph{ps}  $\rightsquigarrow$ \emph{pdf}.
\end{itemize}

En los procesos de conversión puede suceder que algunas gráficas
tapen texto. Se debe observar el \emph{pdf} para verificar que eso
no ha sucedido. Si hay texto oculto se debe editar la gráfica,
recortando el marco que realmente contiene la imagen y no espacio vacio.

%% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fin del cuerpo del documento
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio para colocar el nombre del archivo *.bib (sin la extensión .bib) que contiene
% las referencias bibliográficas del artículo utilizando el estilo bibliográfico BibTeX
% "\bibliography{.}"
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \bibliography{references}
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% //// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \appendix% !no modificar esta línea¡
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Espacio para ubicar los apéndices: tablas y gráficas
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fin del artículo
% **** --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

refrences.bib:

```
@ARTICLE{Borges-05,
  AUTHOR =       {Borges, R.},
  TITLE =        {{Análisis de supervivencia de pacientes con diálisis peritoneal}},
  JOURNAL =      {Revista Colombiana de Estadistica},
  YEAR =         {2005},
  volume =       {28},
  number =       {2},
  pages =        {243-259},
}

@ARTICLE{Borges-06,
  AUTHOR =       {Brown, M. and Forsythe},
  TITLE =        {{Robust Test for the Equality of Variantes}},
  JOURNAL =      {Journal of the American Statistical Association},
  YEAR =         {1974},
  volume =       {69},
  number =       {346},
  pages =        {364-367},
}

@MASTERSTHESIS{Caballero-86,
  AUTHOR =       {Caballero, S. G.},
  TITLE =        {Un estimador del parámetro g de la distribución g de Tukey},
  SCHOOL =       {{Universidad Nacional de Colombia}},
  YEAR =         {1986},
  type =         {{Tesis de Maestría}},
  address =      {{Facultad de Ciencias. Departamento de Estadística, Bogotá}},
}

@BOOK{Castro-03,
  AUTHOR =       {De Castro, Rodrigo},
  TITLE =        {El universo \LaTeX},
  PUBLISHER =    {Unibiblos},
  YEAR =         {2003},
  edition =      {segunda},
  ADDRESS =      {Universidad Nacional de Colombia, Bogotá}
}

@ARTICLE{Conover-81,
  AUTHOR =       {Conover, W. and Johnson, M. E. and Johnson, M.},
  TITLE =        {{A Comparative Study of Tests for Homogeneity of Variances, With Applications to the Outer Continental Shelf Bidding Data}},
  JOURNAL =      {Technometrics},
  YEAR =         {1981},
  volume =       {23},
  pages =        {351-361},
}

@BOOK{DAPD97,
  AUTHOR =       {DAPD},
  TITLE =        {Población estratificación y aspectos socioeconómicos de Santa Fe de Bogotá},
  PUBLISHER =    {Departamento Administrativo de Planeación Distrital},
  YEAR =         {1997},
  address =      {Bogotá},
}

@BOOK{Dodge-85,
  AUTHOR =       {Dodge, Y.},
  TITLE =        {{A}nalysis of {E}xperiments with {M}issing {D}ata},
  PUBLISHER =    {John Wiley \& Sons},
  YEAR =         {1985},
  address =      {{New York}},
}


@BOOK{Milliken-84,
  AUTHOR =       {Milliken, G.A. and Johnson, D.E. },
  TITLE =        {{Analysis of Messy Data}},
  PUBLISHER =    {Van Nostrand Reinhold},
  YEAR =         {1984},
  volume =       {I},
  series =       {of Designed Experiments},
  address =      {New York},
}

@BOOK{Searle-92,
  AUTHOR =       {Searle, S. R. and Casella, G. and McCulloch, C.},
  TITLE =        {{Variance Components}},
  PUBLISHER =    {John Wiley \& Sons},
  YEAR =         {1992},
  address =      {New York},
}

@Manual{R,
    title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
    author = {{R Development Core Team}},
    organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
    address = {Vienna, Austria},
    year = {2007},
    note = {{ISBN} 3-900051-07-0},
    url = {http://www.R-project.org},
}

@ARTICLE{Santana,
  AUTHOR =       {Santana, Juan Camilo},
  TITLE =        {Predicción de series temporales con redes neuronales: una aplicación a la inflación colombiana},
  JOURNAL =      {Revista Colombiana de Estadistica},
  YEAR =         {2006},
  volume =       {29},
  number =       {1},
  pages =        {77-92},
}
```

I have already Done

```
latex
bibtex
latex
```

and It Did not work

```
error: Citation Santana Undefined
....,
....
      Citation R Undefined
```

they use ISO-8859-1

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, could you please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem and add a little document, a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem? Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.

Comment: I downloaded the `revcoles.cls version 2.5` file [here](http://www.emis.de/journals/RCE/autores.html) and tried to compile your code and I get no such errors.

Comment: I have the problem in ubuntu but in windows I do not have the problem, I want to add an article but when I compile it does not appear in the document

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Santana or R cited in your example...

- Make sure bibtex does find the bibliography file (Perhaps need to set 
  BIBINPUTS?)
- Make sure the bibligraphy is OK (check for missing/redundant {})
- Make sure the citation in your text is exactly like the entry in your .bib file
- Take a look at the *.bbl file, it should have an entry for each referenced item